# PHP PDO Change Table Status To Ban User

Tags: php, pdo

I've successfully after looking at other peoples code made a working login system for my software, I'm not very fluent in PHP or PDO so I would really appreciate some help with my following issue.

This is the whole code:

```
if ( isset($_GET['username'], $_GET['password'], $_GET['hwid']) ) {

//We use prepared statements, why? Because it's much more safe.
$userStatement = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM ROE WHERE username = :u AND password = :p');
//We bind each param, no need to use htmlspecialchars or real_escape_string since PDO will do this for us
$userStatement->bindParam(':u', $_GET['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$userStatement->bindParam(':p', $_GET['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
//We only continue when the statement is succesfully executed.
if ( $userStatement->execute() ) {
    echo $userStatement->fetchColumn(0) > 0 ? '5352978916' : '0017577757';
}

//We use prepared statements, why? Because it's much more safe.
$userStatement1 = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM ROE WHERE hwid = :h');
//We bind each param, no need to use htmlspecialchars or real_escape_string since PDO will do this for us
$userStatement1->bindParam(':h', $_GET['hwid'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
//We only continue when the statement is succesfully executed.
if ( $userStatement1->execute() ) {
    echo $userStatement1->fetchColumn(0) > 0 ? '<br /><br />4201426523' : '<br /><br />8940042580' . $userStatement = $connect->prepare("UPDATE ROE SET status='2' WHERE username=':u'");
}
```

}

This line of code is what tells me if the user has logged in correctly:

```
        echo $userStatement1->fetchColumn(0) > 0 ? '<br /><br />4201426523' : '<br /><br />8940042580' . $userStatement = $connect->prepare("UPDATE ROE SET status='2' WHERE username=':u'");
```

When the website displays 4201426523 the field is correct and when the website displays 8940042580 it is incorrect. Now I've tried adding a banning function which will work if the website displays 8940042580 it should change the users 'status' in my phpmyadmin database to 2 however it's not working.

Could someone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are only preparing query in the last if statement:

```
$userStatement = $connect->prepare("UPDATE ROE SET status='2' WHERE username=':u'");
```

without executing it with

```
$userStatement->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement doesn't make any sense:

```
echo $userStatement1->fetchColumn(0) > 0 ? 
    '<br /><br />4201426523' : 
    '<br /><br />8940042580' . $userStatement = $connect->prepare("UPDATE ROE SET status='2' WHERE username=:u");
```

When the result of `fetchColumn(0)` is 0, you are attempting to output the string `'<br /><br />8940042580'` concatenated to the result object from a `prepare` statement, which should be giving you an "object could not be converted to string" error.

I think what you wanted to write is:

```
if ($userStatement1->fetchColumn(0) > 0) {
    echo '<br /><br />4201426523';
}
else {
    echo '<br /><br />8940042580';
    $userStatement = $connect->prepare("UPDATE ROE SET status='2' WHERE username=:u");
    $userStatement->bindParam(':u', $_GET['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $userStatement->execute();
}
```

Comment: Hi I've tried your code, however, it's not working I don't get any errors it works at logging in but does not work when changing the HWiD?

Comment: Hi Jack, I think the problem might have been that you had single quotes around `:u` in the `UPDATE` query which I hadn't noticed. See my edit, can you give that a try?